# Hibernate vs. JDBC for dynamic database connection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, native

I have requirement of running SQL to database which will be selected by user, there are around 10K databases and connection string is stored in different database say host database.

Requirement is to 
1. Connect to Host Database (Hibernate works perfectly) 
2. Take the connection string from #1 
3. Run SQL to new connection string 
4. Disconnect the new connected database.

Hibernate is used for #1 which is working fine and also for #3 call we are using following

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = transactionInitImpl.createSessionFactory(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword, sessionType);
```

Using this sessionfactory we are able to fire SQL, keeping connection pool size to 1. This is working but I feel is slow.

Is using native way of connection (connection/statement/resultset) will going to be fast or it will be same or is there any other good way of performing this?

Comment: Creating a sesison factory is a **heavy** operation, normally done once and only once. If your goal is to "fire SQL", Hibernate brings absolutely no value. It's an ORM, not an API to execute SQL queries.

Comment: In addition to what @JBNizet said if you still want to continue using Hibernate you can cache `SessionFactory` object for a given database connection URL (using some eviction policy to not keep 10K `SessionFactory` objects and connections).

Comment: THank you @JBNizet lvan - this is really helpful. It reduced the query time significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is a higher level of abstraction, which is build upon JDBC. It allows operating with Java entities instead of tables. So you're able to use more object-oriented code and rely less on low-level SQL queries. Also it gives you many nice features, such as smart caching, built-in transaction support and so on.

If you need to execute simple SQL queries, Hibernate is overkill for you. Use JDBC as it's always faster.